# Adopt AtomicPtr on structs without Send/Sync traits

Tags: rust, atomic, psutil

Recently I'm trying to monitor the system metrics via [`psutil` crate](https://crates.io/crates/psutil). (I know there is another library `heim` with async feature.)

I once used `AtomicPtr` to wrap the static `Process` struct. And the compiler complained nothing. But soon I got run-time errors, when I called the API on the `Process` object.

I finally figured out that the `pid` of the `AtomicPtr<Process>` changed, which led to the error, since the process with new pid did not exist.

Then I tried another way. I implemented the following `ProcessWrapper`, it works. And the `pid` did not change.

**Edit: The `ProcessWrapper` is redundant, `Process` itself is with `Send/Sync`**

Then here comes my questions:

- Why the first method did not work? <del>It is due to the fact that `Process` is without `Send` trait? If so, why compiler just acquiesced it?</del>
- <del>Is there any potential risk in my second implementation on `ProcessWrapper`? If exists, how to eliminate it?</del>
- In the following example code, a more interesting thing is that: When you uncomment the second implementation, both of them work. But why?

```
use psutil::process::Process;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::process;
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicPtr, AtomicU64, Ordering}, Mutex, Arc
};

lazy_static!{
    static ref PROCESS1 : AtomicPtr<Process> = AtomicPtr::new(&mut Process::new(process::id()).unwrap());
    static ref PROCESS2: Arc<Mutex<Process>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(
        Process::new(std::process::id()).unwrap()
    ));

}


fn main() {
    let process1 = unsafe{PROCESS1.load(Ordering::SeqCst).as_ref()}.unwrap();
    //let process2 = &PROCESS2.lock().unwrap(); 
    println!("{}", process1.pid()); // Unexpected! It is different from the real `process::id`
    //println!("{}", process2.pid()); // It performs well, and it also makes the above one valid
    println!("{}", process::id());
}



// redundant, the `Process` is with `Send/Sync` trait
use process_wrapper::*;
mod process_wrapper{
    use psutil::process::{Process, ProcessResult,MemoryInfo};
    use psutil::Percent;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct ProcessWrapper{
        pub p: Process
    }
    
    unsafe impl Send for ProcessWrapper{}
    unsafe impl Sync for ProcessWrapper{}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> AtomicPtr::new(&mut Process::new(process::id()).unwrap())
> ```

You create the `Process` object on the stack, and store a mutable pointer to that *stack* object into the `AtomicPtr`. Once `PROCESS1` has finished initializing, the `Process` object is deallocated, and your `AtomicPtr` is pointing to uninitialized memory.

`psutil:process::Process` is both `Send` and `Sync`. `Arc<Mutex<Process>>` will work fine, and is safe. Not sure why you need an `AtomicPtr`.

Comment: sorry that I misunderstood basic knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: But I still don't understand why the `PROCESS1` works when we uncomment the `PROCESS2`.  Why it is not deallocated as it should have.

Comment: Because `PROCESS2` gets moved into the `Arc`, which correctly handles allocating and freeing the object. `AtomicPtr` does neither - it's literally a raw pointer.